# getProperty() property parameter value (undefined) is not a string.ERROR:

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, app-lab

Please help me with collision in game, there is an issue here. It keeps telling me that object is undefined. Also says Cannot get property "undefined" on element "cdoor1" and for "char" too.

```
CollisionDetector("cdoor1" , true);
CollisionDetector("char" , true);

function CollisionDetector(object, isDoor){

  var playerX = getXPosition("char");
  var playerY = getYPosition("char");
  var objectX = getProperty(object);
  var objectY = getProperty(object);

  var playerWidth = getProperty("char" , "width");
  var playerHeight = getProperty("char" , "width");
  var objectWidth = getProperty(object , "width");
  var objectHeight = getProperty(object , "height");

  if(playerX + playerWidth >= objectX && playerX <= objectX + objectWidth){

    if(playerY + playerHeight >= objectY && playerY <= objectY + objectHeight){

      if(isDoor && !gameOver){

        gameOver = true;
        setScreen("screen_lose");

      }

      else if(isDoor && !gameOver && !getProperty(object,"hidden")){
        hideElement("cdoor1");
        showElement("odoor1");

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full source code that includes the `getXPosition` function? Seem like you pass the string as the object. `"cdoor1"` & `"char"` are not objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to change put getX and getY positions for object instead of getProperty();
Sorry for my mistake and thank you all for help!

Answer (score 0):

When using constructors, you'll need to add them as variables with "new" like so:

```
var cdoor1 = new CollisionDetector("cdoor1" , true);
var char = new CollisionDetector("char" , true);
```

You can read up on it further here if you wish: https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_object_constructors.asp